# One instance of class per thread, C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdout

I'm writing a logging-utility for a multithreaded application which I'd like to be able to call in a std::cout-like manner:

Thread 1:

```
Logger::log << "First message" << Logger::end;
```

Thread 2:

```
Logger::log << "Second message" << Logger::end;
```

Once `Logger::end` is passed to the log that message should be flushed to file/screen/network/whatever the log goes to. In order to handle concurrent writes to the log without mixing up messages my idea is to have one `Logger::log`instance for each thread, these instances then share access to a threadsafe queue with a worker thread dedicated to popping new messages and writing them to file/screen etc.

One way to implement that I guess is to have some sort of a multi-singleton returning an instance depending on which thread id is calling it (mapping from thread id to log stored in a std::map perhaps). Is there a better and/or more efficient way?

Are there other designs without the need of one log instance per thread which I have overlooked? How does std::cout handle concurrent access?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the multi-singleton, king among design patterns. Like an ordinary singleton, but even better.

Comment: Have you *seen* how `std::cout` handles concurrent access? That is easy to set up and try.

Comment: From what I've seen it doesn't handle it?

Comment: @Michael Frost It does. It mixes the single invocations to `operator<<`, but it does not race (i.e., no crashes).

Comment: @MichaelFrost: Right, so you have to do better. (To be precise, `std::cout` can be used without data races, but the output from multiple threads can be arbitrarily interleaved.) But it's in any case nothing you want to aspire to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use thread_local singletons:

```
class Logger {
public:
    struct Sentinel{};

    static thread_local Logger log;
    static Sentinel end;

    template<class T>
    Logger& operator<<(T data) {
        stream << data;
        return *this;
    }
    //for endl and so on
    Logger& operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&)) {
        pf(stream);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    Logger(){};
    std::stringstream stream;       
};

thread_local Logger Logger::log;
Logger::Sentinel Logger::end;

template<>
Logger& Logger::operator<<<Logger::Sentinel>(Logger::Sentinel data) {
    stream << std::endl;
    std::cout << stream.str();
    stream.str("");
    return *this;
}
```

Another possible syntax:

```
class Logger_t {
public:
    template<class T>
    Logger_t& operator<<(T data) {
        stream << data;
        return *this;
    }
    //for endl and other stream manipulators
    Logger_t& operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&)) {
        pf(stream);
        return *this;
    }
    void flush() {
        std::cout << stream.str();
        stream.str("");
    }

private:
    Logger_t(){};
    std::stringstream stream;
    friend Logger_t& Logger();
};

Logger_t& Logger() {
    thread_local Logger_t logger;
    return logger;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    Logger() << "test1 " << "test2" << std::endl;
    Logger() << "test3" << std::endl;
    Logger().flush();
    Logger() << "test4" << std::endl; // <-- Not flushed
}
```

Output:

```
test1 test2
test3
```

EDIT:
I revisited my answer and while it demonstrates the general Idea, the concrete example has a few caveats:

1. While `std::cout` is - by default - thread safe, the individual characters from multiple parallel calls to `operator<<` are still allowed to be interleaved. As far as I can tell, this does at least not happen with gcc and clang on Ubuntu, but to be really portable you might have to guard any accesses to `std::cout` or whatever your logging system uses.
2. You have to make sure that no one passes a reference to a Logger instance to another thread. I don't know, why one should do it, but it might be a surprising limitation for other users, as this is not the case for "normal" singletons. So it might be better to make the buffer variable `stream` `thread_local` instead of the logger.

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip that multi-singleton.

Have a global `log`.  `log << whatever` generates an intermediate log object.  An `intermediate log object << whatever` shares the internal state of the intermediate log object with its return value.

When the shared internal state is finally destroyed, it atomically writes it to the log out.

So each line (of source) is atomically sent out.

If you want to do multi-line logging, you have to use `auto&& l = log << whatever`, then use `l << more stuff` when you want to append.  When the `l` object is destroyed it is sent out to the log output.

For industrial quality:

On `log` and `intermediate_log`, `<< X` should work iff `ostream << X` works.

`intermediate_log` should store a `std::shared_ptr<std::stringstream>` with a magic deleter, which it forwards its input to, then return a copy of itself (the copy allows lifetime extension with `auto` syntax).

The magic deleter should write the `stringstream` contents to the actual output log, possibly via an async queue or something (if there is lots of contention, and writing is slow).

Comment: How do you do the atomic writing of the final line? With a global mutex?

Comment: @kerreksb Depends.  If your `std::cout` already synchronizes individual string writes (as opposed to character), just write out a string (I think some do that).  Otherwise, for quick and dirty, we use a global lock.  For better, we have a global synchronized queue which we process from one thread (this reduces lock time to the time required to move a string onto the queue, or move it off at the other end).  Lots of options.

Comment: Can you make `std::cout` make such guarantees? I couldn't find anything to that effect in the standard.

Comment: @kerrek I said some implementations may do that already: no, that is not required by the standard.  The more general solution requires a lock around either a queue to an async serial printer, or a lock around printing itself.  The first is more efficient, as your code does not wait for the file/screen io to complete, bit the risk that the app crashes with the queue unflushed remains.

Comment: A promising approach would be to have (possibly lock-free) SPSC thread-local queues into which each thread sinks its log data, and a single printer thread that reaps those queues and prints. That could be made to work without any locking, although you'd need to add some sleeping mechanics. (At thread exit, the local queue would need to set a flag and the reaper thread would do the actual destroying of the queue.)

Comment: @kerreksb lock free doesn't mean faster: it just handles priority inversion and other cases better.  A simple global many-producer, single-consumer queue where the producers pre-allocate their links, splice only in the lock, and consumer just takes the entire queue, would keep contention minimal (1-2 memory accesses+lock+unlock), be much simpler, and solves the problem.  I would only go further if profiling told me it was a problem.

Comment: How do you avoid throwing destructors?  From C++11 onward, an uncaught exception escaping from a destructor will normally crash the program via `terminate()` since destructors are `noexcept` by default (and that default should generally not be overridden, to avoid the colliding exception problem).  Generally, writing to a log involves resource manipulation that can not be guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: @adam preallocate the resource in the shared state.  Append to resource in `<<`.  In dtor, just move preallocated list node into global write queue (lock then move/splice).  Actual write happens in worker thread "somewhere", as we do not generally want to wait for io.

Answer (score 0):

According to direct question, the best reasonable way would be just to store a logger like a `thread_local` variable inside singleton.

But I strongly against your idea in general. You should flush your logs to the file *directly from the message source thread*. Otherwise you could possible lose some messages when your program crash between message been send to queue and actually written on disc.

Comment: Well, for many logging requirements, that is an expensive luxury that has too great a performance cost.  An extreme example would be when logging to a network drive with high latency.

Comment: @MartinJames, Then you can log to database, or log to separate service. It is more complecated but better than spending a couple of weeks in finding "why your application crash when everything gores great according to logs"

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest the trivial solution here , but I go with regular singleton class with thread safety :

```
class Logger{
   private:
     std::mutex mtx;
     ...
   public:
   void log (const std::string& logToPrint){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mtx);
      //do any logging here..
   } 
};
```